# Get inner list from list of list C#

Tags: c#

I am working with C# and I have a following

```
List<List<UserObj>> obj;
```

How do I get the inner list (`List<UserObj>`) of obj?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.yodawgyo.com/wp-content/uploads/1846/yo-dawg-yo-dawg01-480x440.jpg

Comment: Do you know what your object is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't *an* inner list - there are many of them.

You can get a specific one, for example: `obj[0]`.

Alternatively you can concatenate the contents of all the lists into one long list:

```
var result = obj.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Phew!! SelectMany() was there just below to Select() but never did i think of trying it. This works like wonder.. :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
List<UserObj> users = obj[myindex];
```

or

```
foreach(List<UserObj> users in obj)
{
  foreach(UserObj user in users)
  {
    // now we have an individual user from our list of lists
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I oversimplifying it?

```
foreach( var innerList in outerList ) {
    foreach( var item in innerList ) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: dang...should have seen that coming...5 of the same answers all at once :-P

Answer (score 1):

It's a list of lists.  You can enumerate over the `obj` list.  Each item is a `List<UserObj>`.

```
foreach (List<UserObj> innerList in obj)
{
    // do something with innerlist
}
```